# DBInputFormat multiple records processing

Tags: database, hadoop

When we connect to a RDBMS like MYSQL using Hadoop we usually get a record from the DB into a user-defined class which extends DBWritable and Writable. If our SQL query generates N records as output then the act of reading a record into the user-defined class is done N times. Is there a way in which I can get more number of records into the mapper at the same time instead of 1 record each time ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you think Hadoop causes N `SELECT` statements under the hood. That is not true. As you can see in [`DBInputFormat`'s source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.4/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.java?view=markup), it creates chunks of rows based on what Hadoop deems fit.

Obviously, each mapper will have to execute a query to fetch some data for it to process, and it might do so repeatedly, but that's still definitely nowhere near the number of rows in the table.

However, if performance degrades, you might be better off just dumping the data into HDFS / Hive and processing it from there.